# InAppBrowser overlaps Admob Banner in ionic 3 application

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am making an application for Android using ionic 3. I want to show a website in my app and for this I am using cordova InAppBrowser plug-in and that is working fine.

The problem is that when the website is displayed in inAppBrowser (not external browser) admob banner ad is hidden behind inAppBrowser, and when I close the browser the banner ad is shown. I am using the AdMobPro plug-in to show the banner ad. Simply, I want to show the banner ad and inAppBrowser both simultaneously.

Please help me to resolve this.